# Service + Service installer

Tags: c#, service, installation, dependencies

I am putting together a simple poller service for one of our web applications, however I would like to be able to update the service by simply swapping the DLL over.

I add the dll as a depencancy and it all works nicely the code can see it in VS and it compiles and the installer compiles and it installs and runs, however when I exclude the depended on dll in the installer it will still compile then it fails to start and complains that it can't find a file that it needs even though it is in the right place and has rights to access it.

Is this acheivable (I'm pretty sure that it is)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to restart the service? And how exactly do you imagine that would work? Imagine the service is in the middle of executing some method, what should happen when you switch the DLL? And what *exactly* is the error you're getting?

Comment: stopping / starting the service is fine, at the moment I have to uninstall / re-install the service to update it. I'll post the error message in a short while.

Comment: Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'service, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'service, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Service_Core.Service_Core.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it works a load better with the dll in the same folder as the service is installed in not in the windows folder (used procmon to find the errors when the service was starting up).

Could have also put the dll in the GAC (but I prefer it when I have 100% control over the file).